# Birkhoff Ergodic Theorem for sequences of functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

The Birkhoff Ergodic Theorem provides us with almost sure convergence of the series
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}f\circ T^j$$
provided that $f\in L^1$ and $T$ is measure preserving. Can this same type of convergence be guaranteed if the observable $f$ is dependent on the index $j$ with $f_j\in L^1$ for every $j$? Or example if
$$f=f_j = \prod_{k=0}^{j-1}a_k(x).$$
I suspected the answer to this question would be yes since both $f\circ T^j$ and $f_j\circ T^j$ would be dependent on $j$ however I my only concern here would be that the $j$ dependence appears in the function that has nothing to do with $x$.

Comment: That would be a really different theorem, though. A significantly stronger one.

Comment: @FShrike I guess I thought there may have been something here where I could apply the result directly since (for example) I could define $f$ dependent on the same index resembling compositions as $T$ and argue that this could still possibly be viewed as a sequence $f\circ T^j$. Certainly, if $f$ was dependent on another index we may require an alternative result. In the example I have suggesting we could view the $j^\mathrm{th}$ term in the series $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}f\circ T^j$ as $k=0$ to $j$ products of $a_k(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

If the sequence $f_n$ converges almost everywhere and in $L^1$ to a function $f$, then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}f_{n-j}\circ T^j =\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}f\circ T^j
$$
almost everywhere and in $L^1$ (the right-hand side is well defined because of Birkhoff's ergodic theorem).

For a proof you can see for example Corollary 1.9 in [Mañé's book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-70335-5). Note that the argument, unsurspringly, uses Birkhoff's ergodic theorem, but it is not really immediate.